# "Sub mdichild_Shown() " event is not firing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

mdiparent Code:

```
Private Sub mdiparent_Load(
   mdichild.Show()
```

mdichild Code:

```
Private Sub mdichild_Load()
    Me.MdiParent = Project1.mdiparent
```

mdichild.Designer.vb Code:

```
Me.Controls.Add(Me.compont1)
CType(Me.compont1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
```

a) error is only for mdichild,
`mdichild_Shown()` event will fire if i comment `Me.MdiParent = Project1.mdiparent` line

b) also `mdichild_Shown()` , event will fire if i move  line `Me.Controls.Add(Me.compont1)` after `ISupportInitialize).EndInit()` line. (but `Me.Controls.Add(Me.compont1)`line will be automatically moved up if any design changes are done.)

How do i solve this problem, other than,using the above solutions?

Comment: In `Sub mdiparent_Load() => mdichild.MdiParent = Me mdichild.Show()`. No idea what `Me.compont1` is. Don't tamper with the Designer code. The first save will rewrite the content. If you need to add a child control, add it in the `mdichild` constructor or `Form.Load` event.

Comment: @jimi the component here is AxMSFlexGrid1 `CType(Me.AxMSFlexGrid1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()` 
`Friend WithEvents AxMSFlexGrid1 As AxMSFlexGridLib.AxMSFlexGrid` but it works properly for picturebox `PicCommonQry As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`
`CType(Me.PicCommonQry, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()`